# What does gcc (and clang) do if you specify more than one optimization flag together?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

The build system is impossible to figure out, although it IS possible to configure an additional flag: In trying to do some quick-and-dirty tests, I'm able to inject an additional -O3 flag to see how the program's performance is under -O3 optimization.

However, -O2 is also specified, and is specified *afterwards*.

The question is, is it well-defined that for the compiler only the last optimization flag will stick? Or will it (I hope) go with the highest-specified optimization level? Or is it undefined? It is definitely not complaining or erroring out, that's for sure.

Comment: There's nothing in the C++ programming language that specifies the compiler's behavior in this regard. Unless this is explicitly documented in the compiler's documentation the only thing you can do is figure it out yourself by writing some code that produces different assembly depending on the optimization level, then try multiple optimization level options and see which version comes out. Shouldn't be a difficult experiment.

Comment: `-O<something>` may cause a compilation failure. There's no unified "compile this c++ program" interface.

Answer (score 3):

It's all in the documentation. From [gcc optimize options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options):

> If you use multiple -O options, with or without level numbers, the last such option is the one that is effective.

---

> What does gcc (and clang) do if you specify more than one optimization flag together?

The compilers you are using use the optimization `-O` option that was specified last on the command line.

> is it well-defined that for the compiler only the last optimization flag will stick?

It's documented in your compilers documentation.

> Or will it go with the highest-specified optimization level?

No.

> Or is it undefined?

No.